# can't uninstall app

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung, uninstallation

My Samsung Galaxy Mega with Android 4.2.2 will not allow me to uninstall an app (Gravity Screen 1.80.8) even when I stop its running service.  When I select it from downloaded apps the Stop and Uninstall buttons are greyed out, even after waiting for over a minute. How may I remove it?

Comment: Take a look at the logcat mesages, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [ES File Explorer](http://www.appsapk.com/es-file-explorer/) and uninstall Gravity Screen by going to App Manager then select Gravity Screen and uninstall it.

Answer (score 4):

Found this on YouTube:

Go to Settings -> Security -> Phone Administrators, then un-check this app and proceed to uninstall it by the usual means.

Comment: What do I do if this doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

Open the Gravity Screen application. On the lower bottom there is uninstall button. You can uninstall from there.